# Add a title beside MultiSelect SelectAll Checkbox in prime react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, primereact

I have a project with nextjs and typescript.In this project I use primereact as UI kit. my problem is I want add a text beside MultiSelect select all checkbox. something like this

[image]

Prime react add a prop as panelHeaderTemplate but I can't figure out how can I use and implement this.

Tnx in advanced for any effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Code Sandbox showing how to do it: https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-fast-e5jsgj

[image]